# Associating .jnlp with javaws

Tags: java, jnlp

I have an application that is being deployed via JNLP on Windows XP. I have created a shortcut on the user desktops pointing to http://myserver/myapp.jnlp. In the folder options on XP, I have set the jnlp extension to use javaws. Despite this, the desktop shortcut still appears as a web link (using the browser icon) and when clicked, results in a browser being launched (which in turn, successfully launches the app).

This is a minor inconvenience as the application does get launched but I would prefer if the browser weren't involved. Any suggestions on how to get the app to launch directly (without the browser) would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two simple options ...

1. change your shortcuts target to "javaws destination.jnlp" or
2. add shorcut tag to your jnlp file and javaws will create application shortcut for you

Second solution is much better because it's cross-platform.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I created a new shortcut to "javaws http://myurl/myapp" and it worked fine. FYI, I had been using option 2 but this stopped working, option 1 successfully works around this.

Comment: Did you try to clear Java cache, "reinstall" application or create shorcut manualy from Java control panel?

Comment: Originally, I was running Java 6u20 but I downgraded to 6u16. I removed 6u20, cleared the cache, rebooted, installed 6u16 and started the app. The app launched fine but didn't create the shortcut. I didn't know about creating a shortcut from the control panel, I just checked and the option is there but ghosted.